# Loading more than 10000 product data in auto increment field

Tags: mysql, ajax, autocomplete

I need to fetch records from the products table to an auto-increment dropdown field if suppose it is a table data I would have done pagination and would have retrieved 10-20 data per page. So now how to handle this situation where I need to show all thousand records in an auto-increment dropdown field. I am now loading all products in one API(REST) request and storing it in an array and using it, but it takes around 10s or more to load all those data. Any optimization suggestion will be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a lookahead field instead of listing everything. You can also have a list of first few and then add ...More as an option. Clicking on that loads the next few.